# Bitwise treatment of objects in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, bit-manipulation, bit

So I was attempting to a bitwise "XOR" between two objects in python, as part of an xor-swap routine (just as a demonstrative example). But I noticed that the bitwise xor doesn't work on strings.

I did some exploring on stackoverflow and came across:

[Bitwise xor python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436446/bitwise-xor-python)

The answer is unsatisfactory, namely because I want to be able to do, raw byte level manipulation with my data. Is this simply impossible in python?

I'm hoping someone can point me to a library that will let me be able to treat all objects as blocks of bytes that I am free to manipulate with familiar operators such as "xor"

Comment: i guess you could use pickle?

Comment: Python integers are arbitrary length, you can convert the strings to padded integer and use the bitwise xor operator on them.

Comment: Python's object model doesn't allow bytewise access to its object internals. Concerning strings, it doesn't even allow you to modify them in any way at all.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312571/fast-xoring-bytes-in-python-3

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in Python.  You want the `bytearray` type to manipulate data in place.

```
>>> b = bytearray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> for i in xrange(len(b)):
...   b[i] ^= 255
...
>>> b
bytearray(b'\xfe\xfd\xfc\xfb\xfa\xf9\xf8\xf7')
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are not byte arrays in Python, like they are in C. Internally they are UTF-32 (UCS-4) IINM.

Python is very hackable. If something is not there, you can bend it to do what you want most of the time:

```
>>> class MyBytes(bytes):
...     def __xor__(self, v):
...         return bytes(a ^ b for a, b in zip(self, v))
...
>>> MyBytes('!7-x9*=x9x49"!x:*9,', 'ascii') ^ MyBytes('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'ascii')
b'you are a lazy brat'
```

This is Python 3, I guess you can figure out how to do that in earlier versions.

Comment: "Internally they are UTF-32" → Not since [PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/).